# How to reference the int variable to another script which is in another GameObject in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use the Health variable from MainHero at another gameobject. However, all the answer I've found were relevant only if two scripts are tied to one Object. Is there a way I can GetComponent to tranfer only one variable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look for GetComponent in the unity documentation

Comment: your heal variable should be public. With GenComonponent you can find classes in gameobjects. You can also use Find("gameObjecname") to find gameobjects in the scene. Not very advisable but does the work. Also FindComponentOfType will find your class type in the scene to access its data https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html .If your field is public or you put above [SerializeField] you can attach references to other components by dragging them into your field in the editor. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

first.

```
public class MainHero : MonoBehaviour
{
   public int health;

   .
   .
   .
}
```

second.

```
public class AnotherHero : MonoBehaviour
{
   MainHero mainHero;
   int anotherHealth;

   void Start()
   {
      mainHero = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("YOUR MAINHERO OBJECT TAG").GetComponent<MainHero>();

      anotherHealth = mainHero.health;
   }
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Or you can use `mainHero.health` directly.

and after this, assign your MainHero script to your MainHero object and
AnotherHero script to your AnotherHero object.

If you get a NullReferenceException, Make sure you put the MainHero's tag name in

```
FindGameObjectWithTag("YOUR MAINHERO OBJECT TAG").GetComponent<MainHero>();
```

Select MainHero object in your Hierarchy and check the Inspector window.
You will see the Tag under your Object name.
[image]

Like in the Above picture, If your tag is set to Untagged.
Click Untagged and you will see Add Tag at the bottom of the dropdown.
Click it and add Your own tag and set the tag as you created.

Finally, put the tag that you've created in

```
("YOUR MAINHERO OBJECT TAG")
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply, I did like it like it is shown in your examples, but I got the following error in Unity 
"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: I have assigned the tag, however it shows me that the following line is creating an error.
 anotherHealth = mainHero.health;
I have checked and everything is written correctly and the code itself shows no mistakes.

Comment: @WAYRT Did you set your MainHero's health to public? it should work.

Comment: Everything is on public. I do have the main health edited in Another Hero and then referenced in another, third script but the error states that the problem is the Another Hero script.